# IPtables errors

Tags: shell-script, iptables

I am working on a project. I am trying to write iptables rules to control network traffic.

I have written some rules. When I try to apply them to the boxes that I am working on I either get locked out or the error out.

Some of the rules do get applied, but it appears that they are in a random order.

I am working on centos 5 with iptables version 1.3.5

Below are the rules I am working with.

http://pastebin.com/gjhAmBLm

Some of the errors that I am getting are as follows.

```
Starting firewall:
Dropped all existing rules
Set Policy to drop all traffic

Added SSH rules
./firewall.sh: line 64: -A: command not found
./firewall.sh: line 65: -A: command not found
Added HTTP traffic
allow bidirectional sql traffic
iptables v1.3.5: host/network `eth3' not found
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
iptables v1.3.5: host/network `eth3' not found
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.
allow ICMP in and out
./firewall.sh: line 84: -A: command not found
./firewall.sh: line 85: $,iptables: command not found
```

done.

Here is a printout of ifconfig:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:17:57:C1:30
          inet addr:10.1.3.2  Bcast:10.1.3.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:17ff:fe57:c130/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:21 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:24 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:5290 (5.1 KiB)  TX bytes:5348 (5.2 KiB)
          Interrupt:169 Memory:fe9e0000-fea00000

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:04:23:9F:0C:C6
          inet addr:192.168.1.34  Bcast:192.168.3.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::204:23ff:fe9f:cc6/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1285 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1079 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:166472 (162.5 KiB)  TX bytes:141002 (137.6 KiB)

eth3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:17:57:C1:32
          inet addr:10.1.2.3  Bcast:10.1.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:17ff:fe57:c132/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:19 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:29 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:5203 (5.0 KiB)  TX bytes:5962 (5.8 KiB)
          Interrupt:90 Memory:fe7e0000-fe800000

eth4      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:17:57:C1:33
          inet addr:10.1.1.2  Bcast:10.1.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:17ff:fe57:c133/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:20 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:26 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:5250 (5.1 KiB)  TX bytes:5747 (5.6 KiB)
          Interrupt:122 Memory:fe7a0000-fe7c0000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:55 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:55 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:4902 (4.7 KiB)  TX bytes:4902 (4.7 KiB)
```

I cannot mess with ETH2. It always has to be up. If I block the connection it will kill my SSH session. I am using a system called deterlab. I am a college student, we have access to this system to test out projects on. ETH2 is the systems control network.

Thanks for the help. If you have any questions please post them in the comments and I will answer them.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that "Set Policy to drop all traffic" this should be at the bottom. I moved the rules to drop all traffic, but I forgot to move the echo statement.

Comment: Don't do iptables this way. `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` (`iptables-restore`) is far more efficient and just as easy to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is straight script debugging. If you run your script with `-x` you'll see the expansions of your variables.

Running with `bash -x testcode.sh` (for your filename as `testcode.sh`), line 64 becomes visible as follows,

```
-A INPUT -i eth3 -p tcp  --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

The reason for this is that this line uses `$iptables` as its action instead of `$IPTABLES`. Variables (as like most things in the Unix/Linux CLI) are case sensitive.

Continuing on, the parameters to `iptables` on line 79 are syntactically wrong:

```
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -s $ETH -p tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
```

The `-s` flag expects a *source address/subnet* and you have given it `$ETH3`, an *interface name*. Did you mean `-i $ETH` perhaps?

Now, line 85. The start of the line is just plain broken (initial spurious characters, wrong case on the variable):

```
$,iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 0 -s $ETH -d 10.1.2.0/24 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to have a look at errors displayed. They tell you which lines produce error, and in your case, some reasons are obvious. See:

```
./firewall.sh: line 85: $,iptables: command not found
```

You made a typo by adding a comma between `$` and `iptables`.

Then, you should be aware that variables names are case-sensitive. Thus, `$IPTABLES` is different from `$iptables`.

Once you fixed those issues, your lines for allowing SSH should be quite good (watch out the output rule, where you have to specify the output interface `-o`, not `-i`)

```
$IPTABLES -A INPUT -i $ETH2 -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -A OUTPUT -o $ETH2 -p tcp  --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```